# JAVA | Error al revolver ARRAY | Tomar 5 nombres y devolver 5 nombres

Tags: java

Error:

> "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - >Erroneous tree type: <   any   >"

```
import java.util.*;

public class Pruebas123 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       String lista[] = tomaDatos();
       muestraNombres(lista[]);
    }

    //El siguiente método toma 5 nombres del usuario
    public static String tomaDatos(){
        String nombres[];
        Scanner scaneo = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Escribe 5 nombres: ");
        nombres = new String [5];
        for(int i = 0 ; i<5 ; i++){
            String nombre = scaneo.nextLine();
            nombres[i]=nombre;
        }
        return nombres[];
    }

    //Siguiente método muestra el contenido del array lista.
    public static String muestraNombres(String lista[]){
        System.out.println("La lista de nombres es la siguiente: ");
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
            System.out.println(lista[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En primer lugar estás tratando de que una variable de tipo `String array`, tome el valor de un solo `String` que es el tipo de dato que devuelve el método `tomaDatos()`.

El método `tomaDatos()`, menciona que además de ser estático, devuelve un `String`, pero estás tratando de devolver un `Array` de `String`

```java
public static String tomaDatos(){
        String nombres[];
        //code
        return nombres; // debería ser algo de tipo String, además no debe de llevar []
}
```

---

Tu código quedaría más o menos

```java
//El siguiente método toma 5 nombres del usuario
    public static String[] tomaDatos(){
        String nombres[]; 
        Scanner scaneo = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Escribe 5 nombres: ");
        nombres = new String [5];
        for(int i = 0 ; i<5 ; i++){
            String nombre = scaneo.nextLine();
            nombres[i]=nombre;
        }
        return nombres; //no es necesario poner []
    }

    //Siguiente método muestra el contenido del array lista.
    public static String[] muestraNombres(String lista[]){
        System.out.println("La lista de nombres es la siguiente: ");
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
            System.out.println(lista[i]);
        }
        return lista;//tienes que retornar la lista, sin []
    }
```

Para que `String lista[]` tome los datos que devuelve `tomaDatos()`, este método tiene que devolver un dato de tipo `String[]` también.

El método `muestraNombre()`, mencionaba que se devolvía algo pero faltaba la sentencia `return`, así que la he añadido, para que retorne un dato de tipo `String[]`según se especifica en su declaración.

Para devolver un `Array` no se deben de poner los corchetes.

---

El método `muestraNombres()` podría ser `void`, y serviría de igual forma.

```java
//Recibe la lista y solo la imprime cuando el método es llamado
public static void muestraNombres(String lista[]){
        System.out.println("La lista de nombres es la siguiente: ");
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
            System.out.println(lista[i]);
        }
}
```

Comment: Cada día me impresionas más <3

Answer (score 1):

Tenías varios inconvenientes, en los comentarios de código escribí que pasa.
Y reemplaza el scanner por **JOptioPane.**

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane
import java.util.*;

public class Pruebas123 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] lista = tomaDatos();
        muestraNombres(lista); // no se pasa con []
    }

    //El siguiente método toma 5 nombres del usuario
    public static String[] tomaDatos(){
        String[] nombres;
        Scanner scaneo = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Escribe 5 nombres: ");
        nombres = new String [5];
        for(int i = 0 ; i<5 ; i++){
            String nombre = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Escribe nombre ", null)
            nombres[i]=nombre;
        }
        return nombres; // no necesitas poner [] para retornar.
    }

    //Siguiente método muestra el contenido del array lista.
    public static String muestraNombres(String[] lista){
        System.out.println("La lista de nombres es la siguiente: ");
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
            System.out.println(lista[i]);
        }
    }
}
```